# Disabling the default MediaRecorder sound in camcorder apps

Tags: java, android, camera, video-recording

I am currently developing an Android Camera/Camcorder application, and I am looking to play my own sounds when capturing video and pictures.

I am using Camera API (not Camera2, I will be using this later) to develop the app

When capturing pictures, using Camera.takePicture(), I have successfully disabled the shutter sound using CameraInfo.canDisableShutterSound() and Camera.enableShutterSound(false)

When capturing video though, as soon as I have the MediaRecorder object start capturing frames, the default "bloop" noise plays at the same time as mine. Is there a way to disable the MediaRecorder sound, similar to Camera.enableShutterSound(false), that I am missing in the API docs? Is there a system setting I can request to be change from my app? Or am I out of luck?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?